# TypeScript w/ Svelte, how to set the typing for: `Parent.Child`

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

What I want is a way to export a group of related components as one component. Using an Accordion component as an example, what I want to be able to do is:

```html
<script language='ts'>
  import { Accordion } from '$lib/components/Accordion';
</script>

<Accordion>
  <Accordion.Item> /* ish */ </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item> /* ish */ </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

If my project were JS, I could simple do:

```js
// src/lib/components/Accordion/index.js
import Accordion from "./Accordion.svelte";
import AccordionItem from "./AccordionItem.svelte";

Accordion.Item = AccordionItem;

export { Accordion };
```

Or if this were React+TS (my primary skillset), I would do:

```js
// Accordion.tsx
import { AccordionItem } from './AccordionItem';
export const Accordion: FC<Props> & { Item: FC<AccordionItemProps> } = (props) => { /* ish */ };
Accordion.Item = AccordionItem;
```

I've been looking through the TS/Svelte/SvelteKit docs and have no idea how to properly type `Accordion` so that it'll take `AccordionItem` without complaint.

PS, this is in a SvelteKit project, but I presume that this is more a Svelte/TS question.